# Python Heads and Tails

Tags: python

I need help for a Python game I am currently creating. When running the code it will stay open and do nothing after entering a number of times to flip. Here is what I have so far:

```
# Heads and Tails generator
# User how many times they wish to flip a coin and will recieve the results
CoinTosses = int(input("How many coins do you wish to flip: "))
Heads = 0
Tails = 0
CurrentCoinToss = 0
from random import randint
while CoinTosses != 0:
    CurrentCoinToss == int(randint(1, 2))
    if CurrentCoinToss == 1:
        Heads += 1
        CoinTosses -= 1
    if CurrentCoinToss == 2:
        Tails += 1
        CoinTosses -= 1
print("During this round you recieved: ", Heads, " and", Tails, " Tails!")
input("Press the enter key to exit")
```

What is wrong with this? I have studied my code and nothing SHOULD be wrong.

Comment: You've got an extra `=`.

Comment: And please avoid PascalCase and use snake_case for variables. Refer to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for a Style Guide for Python Code

Comment: CurrentCoinToss  equals 0, then CurrentCoinToss == int(randint(1, 2)) just compares 2 variables (without printing it out or doing something with result)

Comment: Next time, you should try debugging your code instead of just studying it. If you would have either added some extra `print` statements to monitor what is going on or used [pdb (the python debugger)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) to step through your code line by line and watch what happens to your variables, you would have quickly discovered that `CurrentCoinToss` was never changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
CurrentCoinToss == int(randint(1, 2))
```

to this

```
CurrentCoinToss = int(randint(1, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

In the while loop you've written:

```
CurrentCoinToss == int(randint(1, 2))
```

Which actually tests the value of CurrentCoinToss, but doesn't give it a value.

Change it by:

```
CurrentCoinToss = int(randint(1, 2))
```